# How to fix undefined reference to deflate/inflate

Tags: c, gcc, debian, compression, zlib

I am trying to run code that use zlib on Debian by using this command

```
gcc -o new double.c -lz -lm
```

But I have these errors : how to fix the errors please?

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You are trying to use libz, and the linker can't find it. Are you sure it's installed?

Comment: No, How can install it please?

Comment: If it's the same as Ubuntu, and I think it is, it's `apt-get install zlib1g`. Actually, you probably want `apt-get install zlib1g-dev` so you can do `#include <zlib.h>`. I don't know how you manged to compile a program that needs zlib without `zlib.h`.

Comment: The zlib.h file is found inside the  directory of my code so I thought I just needed for like the lib by using -lz

Comment: Re "*The zlib.h file is found inside the directory of my code*", This is incorrect. Do delete it.

Comment: Why? more info please?

Comment: Who knows what relation it has to the the library you are using. You want to use the one for the library you are using.

Comment: I have "zlib.h" inside the code so I just need to like it in correct way.

Comment: No, again, that's wrong. You should use the one that's installed by `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`. To do that, 1) delete all files named `zlib.h` in your project dir. 2) Use `#include <zlib.h>`, not `#include "zlib.h"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the library and the associated header files. This can be done using the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

Note that you have indicated you have a file named `zlib.h` in your project directory. This is wrong. Delete it, and use `#include <zlib.h>` instead of `#include "zlib.h"`. This will use the correct `zlib.h`, the one installed by the above command.